# Linking an image to a URL within a <img class>

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a big problem. I included a "fade script" on my portfolio which fades between thumbnails in my portfolio using jQuery and CSS. Unfortunately it's based on 2 img classes which I'm unable to link.

In other words I like to link the image green.jpg to a URL (in this case a youtube clip in a lightbox).

Anyone know how to solve  this?

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
            <div id="cf">
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE" rel="vidbox" title="caption">
                <img class="bottom" src="img/green.jpg" border="0" />
              </a>
              <img class="top" src="img/a_childish_letter.jpg" />
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width:310px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Thanks a lot! And if it's to any help you can check out the page at http://www.axeltagg.com/test/

Best regards! /Axel

Comment: Do we know how to solve what? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? What do you mean by being 'unable to link' images?

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that you are in a page inside a dir `www.myweb.com/awesome/page.html`. Referencing an image without the starting slash `/` means that your server looks for images in `www.myweb.com/awesome/img/myimg.png`.

But as David said, give more info pls

Comment: I want to link the image "green.jpg" to a youtube clip. But I cant get it to work. You can check out the site at http://www.axeltagg.com/test/ where you can see how the green image with the plus sign on suppose to be a link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the anchor tag to both images. Or set the green image to a higher z-index.

First solution:

Change this:

```
<div class="item">
            <div id="cf">
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE" rel="vidbox" title="caption">
                <img class="bottom" src="img/green.jpg" border="0" />
              </a>
              <img class="top" src="img/a_childish_letter.jpg" />
            </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="item">
            <div id="cf">
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE" rel="vidbox" title="caption">
                <img class="bottom" src="img/green.jpg" border="0" />
              <img class="top" src="img/a_childish_letter.jpg" />
              </a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Second solution:

```
.bottom{
    z-index: 1;/* Try Higher numbers if it doesn't work or add !important */
}
```

I tested it out in Google Chrome and it works!

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot, first solution worked like a charm! I owe u one big time! Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get image URLs
var current_image_top = $('div#cf').children('img.top').attr('src');

var current_image_bottom = $('div#cf').find('a').children('img.bottom').attr('src');

//Set image URLs
$('div#cf').children('img.top').attr('src', 'new_image.jpg');

$('div#cf').find('a').children('img.bottom').attr('src', 'new_image.jpg');
```

Comment: Hi,
Okey, I'm guessing this is some kind of Javascript. Can u help me of where to put this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to save this code as html and open in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="item">
            <div id="cf">
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhi5x7V3WXE" rel="vidbox" 

title="caption">
                <img class="bottom" src="img/green.jpg" border="0" />
              </a>
              <img class="top" src="img/a_childish_letter.jpg" />
            </div>
</div>

<button>Fade Image with top class</button>
<button>Fade Image with bottom class</button>
<script>
$("button:first").click(function() {
  $('div#cf').children('img.top').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("button:last").click(function () {
  $('div#cf').find('a').children('img.bottom').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't get to work either unfortunately :(
The thing I want is just to link the green.jpg image to a youtube clip. But Im guessing it can't be done because its capsuled within a <img class="xxx"> ?